# How the concept of space is defined for Modular Form?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, modular-forms, modular-function

The set of all functions of modular forms of weight $k$ is denoted by $M_k$. It is said in a document that $M_k$ is "clearly a vector space over $C$".

My question is if $M_k$ is a set of functions, how it becomes a vector space? Can anyone explain with an example?

Seems counter-intuitive!

Comment: It's closed under addition and multiplication by scalars in $\mathbb{C}$, and thus is by definition a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Take elements of $M_k$.  Look at the axioms for a vector space and apply those axioms to elements of $M_k$.

Comment: @anomaly we use element to define vector space which are not dynamic as functions. a function is a dynamic object in the sense that it maps to an element based on the argument

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'dynamic' (after all, a function is just a particular kind of set), but a vector space is what its definition says it is. Elements of vector spaces can be functions, matrices, polynomials, random variables, or whatever.

Comment: $C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ is a complex vector space too : if $f,g$ are smooth and $a,b\in \Bbb{C}$ then $af+bg$ is smooth, unlike $M_k$ it is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original concept of vectors applied specifically
to vectors in a [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space)
 where each vector had
a length and direction. This geometric concept was
greatly generalized in the 19th century into the
modern concept of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). The Wikipedia article states

> Vectors in vector spaces do not necessarily have to be arrow-like objects as they appear in the mentioned examples: vectors are regarded as abstract mathematical objects with particular properties, which in some cases can be visualized as arrows. Vector spaces are the subject of linear algebra and are well characterized by their dimension, which, roughly speaking, specifies the number of independent directions in the space. Infinite-dimensional vector spaces arise naturally in mathematical analysis, as function spaces, whose vectors are functions

The $\,M_k\,$ is a good example of these [function spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space).
Several other natural examples appear in the Wikipedia 
article on this topic.